# How can I dispatch from a worker thread back to the XNIO thread in undertow.io?

Tags: java, jboss, undertow

How can I dispatch from a worker thread back to the XNIO thread in undertow.io? Is a callback the solution for this?

```
    if (httpServerExchange.isInIoThread()) {
        httpServerExchange.dispatch(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do something blocking
                // return back to XNIO worker
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Please describe your usecase. In your example, you are doing the exact opposite: dispatching from the IO thread to a worker thread.

Comment: @aramaki I want to be able to do some blocking task on the worker thread and after that task is completed I want to return back to the IO thread to continue non-blocking.